# Can someone trying to convert have mezuzahs on his doorposts?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, shema, mezuzah

When one is going through an orthodox conversion, one is asked to keep all the mitzvoth with the exception of fully keeping the shabbos and putting Tefillin.

I was wondering if this exception also includes the mezouzot. Since one studies the shema in his home everyday. Are there any restrictions on this. I can't seem to find any halachic sources.

Comment: "one is asked to keep as all the mitzvoth with the exception of fully keeping the shabbos and putting Tefillin" can you source this claim?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52774/i-have-a-mezuzah-on-my-door-lintel-but-am-not-jewish-am-i-breaking-the-law/52806#52806

Comment: This is a duplicate of that question, isn't it, @GershonGold?

Comment: @DoubleAA, please see the preceding comment and then delete this one.

Comment: @DoubleAA i can only quote the Beit Din who is converting me.

Comment: I remember learning in sa that a Jew may not give Jewish objects such as tehillim and mezuzas to people who aren't Jewish. Can anyone verify this? Other than this... I know someone who before they converted had a rabbi hold onto their tehillim and mezuzas until after they went to the mikvah

Comment: I know a "potential convert" that used to wear real tefillin (which he received from the Rabbi he was working with...)

Comment: Since you are quoting the bais din that you are working with, this would be a question for them.

Comment: I asked today and i was told that i could put them up but without the Beracha.

Comment: additional sources on the topic: http://dinonline.org/2012/10/23/giving-mezuzah-to-non-jew/ http://www.thejc.com/judaism/rabbi-i-have-a-problem/33606/would-a-mezuzah-be-appropriate-gift-a-catholic-baby http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3615 http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6336

Answer (score 1):

[dinonline says](http://din.org.il/2011/12/20/%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%95/) that it seems it is not allowed unless in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant part from the document you are referring to? Even better could you translate the key sentences?

Comment: This happens to be a list of tshuvos about the subject.  There are not really key sentences.  But as someone living in Israel and most likely knowing Hebrew better than me, I would think you dont need a translation

Comment: It is not for me but for the other readers of the site. In general link-only answers are not considered to be strong answers. Best is to bring in the relevant content into your answer. See [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3414/11501) for more. And the site is in English with many users not  fully understanding Hebrew. Also maybe you will be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ?

Comment: Too late, i was authorised to do it by my Rav. Thank you for your answers

Comment: So... You asked a question Halacha l'maaseh without CYLOR?

Comment: This psak seems to be for a non-Jew, but may be that a man who want to convert is different.

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch states in [סימן יא - הלכות מזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) that a house where a non-Jew lives is exempt from a Mezuza.

> בַּיִת וְכֵן חָצֵר שֶׁגַּם גּוֹי דָּר שָׁם, פָּטוּר

He also states (ibid) that if one affixed a Mezuza in a location that is exempt, and that location later becomes obligated, one has to remove and re-affix it.

> מִשּׁוּם דְּבָעֵינָן תַּעֲשֶׂה וְלֹא מִן הֶעָשׂוּי

So if a soon-to-be-convert affixes Mezuzot, they will have to remember to take them down and re-affix them after the conversion.

(I didn't research this further, but it sounds like asking for trouble; this crucial step could easily be forgotten in the excitement, and then the Ger would be living without a kosher Mezuza.)

<sup>Reminder: Mi Yodea is not a replacement for asking a Rabbi.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure when the mezuzah would have to be affixed in a rental house in the Diaspora, as you can see here - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/79685/501