# When would a convert affix the Mezuzah in the diaspora?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, chutz-laaretz, mezuzah

The Halacha is (as stated in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch  [סימן יא - הלכות מזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2)) that when renting a house in the diaspora one is exempt from Mezuza for the first 30 days. For the first 30 days a rental is not considered a permanent residence.

> **כא:** הַשּׂוֹכֵר בַּיִת בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ, פָּטוּר מִמְּזוּזָה שְׁלֹשִׁים יוֹם, דְּלָא הֲוֵי דִירַת קֶבַע.‏

**If a Ger (a convert) remains in the house they rented before the conversion, do they have to wait 30 days before affixing the Mezuza?**

Do we apply the *Ger is like a newborn* rule, and it's as if they just moved in?
Or do we look at reality and say that they've lived here for a long time and they have the status of permanency?

Inspired by [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79684/501) to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69840/501) - which explains why a Mezuza cannot be affixed earlier than needed.

(In Israel one is obligated to affix the mezuza as soon as one moves in.)

Comment: at first glance it is not linked at all,  the way in which he stays in his home has nothing to do with religion. ואם יש לו בית הכיסא קבוע הוא לא הופך להיות ארעי.  Diverse things are or temporary or fixed  but  +1 for the chidud of the question

Comment: @kouty - where did you find that Hebrew expression? The _newborn_ rule is applied in various places in the Talmud, including not being related to his siblings, and possibly ignoring his previous firstborn. these are all facts that we "change".

Comment: there are dinim of chefza,  e. g.  in masechet Berachot  bet kise kavua,  hazmana milta or sowhat they seems not linked.  additionally  A ger needs not to  wait 13 years before wearing tefilin,  the physical metsiut is not katan shenolad

Comment: @kouty - Why look at the house - the cheftza that is being lived in already. look at the person who has never lived there (as a Jew). But I see your point. Would make a good Chabura. :-)

Comment: yes perhaps you can write it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Concise Code of Jewish Law for Converts* by Rabbi Michael Broyde addresses this question.  It cites *[Agur BeOhalecha](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9A.html?id=PVKQDAEACAAJ)* (page 366:36), by Rabbi Eliyahu Avigdor Feldman, as saying that a convert outside Israel who has been living in a residence for thirty days at the time of conversion must immediately (re-)affix mezuzot after conversion.  No dissenting opinions are cited.