# Seeding free libraries with books with names of Hashem

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, secular-culture

In my area there are (secular) library boxes like [these](http://www.starnewsonline.com/article/20140901/ARTICLES/140909997)

> The idea is a simple variation on the honor system: Take a book,
>   return a book.
>
> Someone, generally a volunteer, puts out a roofed box in a public area
>   and stocks it with books, generally paperbacks or older hardcovers. If
>   you see a book you like, borrow it and bring it back later. You can
>   also leave behind old books you don't want so more people can enjoy
>   them

I'd like to put some books on Science and Torah (which contain Torah verses in Hebrew etc) into those boxes so that people can learn about those topics. However, I am concerned about the possibility that prejudiced people might not treat such books properly.

Is there a ruling on giving such books to libraries that addresses this concern?

Update Feb 1, 2016: My local orthodox Chabad Rabbi said: "I wouldn't put books of kedusha there but English books on Torah and science I think would be fine"

Comment: I've been designated to help manage a Little Free Library on my street.  ❧  People sometimes deposit books which are [unlikely to circulate](https://elissarsloan.com/2022/12/20/so-you-want-to-steward-a-little-free-library/#:~:text=I%E2%80%99m,excite%20me!).  They might be water damaged, several decades old, or poor-quality self-published material.  If space is low, I eventually dump them in the recycling bin.  ❧  Hebrew seforim may also circulate slowly or not at all, even in a Jewish neighborhood.  Non-fiction seems to circulate slowly.  Non-English books seem to circulate even slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask a qualified rav. A few ideas which might be useful to you or him are

- **a Jew is prohibited from throwing away holy writings containing Hashem's name** (from [Devarim 12:2-4](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.12.2?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all), "you shall utterly destroy all the places where the nations that you are driving away worshipped their gods … and you shall obliterate their names from that place. **You shall not do this to Hashem**"
- **it is unclear if the prohibition applies to non-Jews as well** (I don't believe so but don't know for sure) - assuming the majority of people who would take your books are non-Jews might make it easier to do so
- the mechanism you describe (and for sure a library) implies most people will read/keep the books or return them to the exchange boxes. Throwing away the books doesn't appear the normal practice
- geniza is clear for books containing the seven primary names of God (*sheimot hakodesh*) in any language; however **there are many leniencies regarding printed books which do not have the full name of Hashem** (e.g., the word God and similar terms in any language do not require geniza)

R Ari Henkin writes R Moshe Feinstein was of the view that sefarim that have worn out and are no longer usable may be placed in a recycling bin (meaning to be destroyed). In your case the books can still be used but are not meant to be destroyed.

**Bottom line is that you are not throwing away the books, instead you are giving them away to people who in all likelihood will not throw them away either.** In addition to the points above this creates a number of *sfeikot* (doubts).

On the other side *safek d'oraita l'chumra* (one judges strigently when dealing with Torah prohibitions). So we are back at [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10103/how-do-you-cylor-after-posting-on-judaism-stackexchange-com).

See [here](http://www.kosherspirit.com/Article.asp?Issue=13&Article=160) and [here](http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/05/parsha-sheets-garbage-geniza-or-recycle/) for more sources. See also pp. 237-239 in R [Ari Enkin's Da'at V'din](http://rabbienkin.com/bookstore/)

Comment: A couple more data points: (1.) A person may not give a non-Jew a *m'zuza* ([*Bava M'tzi'a* 102a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=102&format=text)) because of the possibility that he will not treat it respectfully (*Sh'eilas Ya'beitz* II, 121; see also [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18196)). For the same reason, a Jew must try to purchase *sifrei Torah* (likely also including other books of Tanach), *t'fillin*, and *m'zuzos* if he finds them in a non-Jew's possession (*Mishna B'rura* 39:17). (2.) A ספק ספיקא may be judged leniently even in Biblical matters.