# What are the mitzvot that a gentile is forbidden to do?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah

I know that some mitzvot like keeping shabbat, putting tefillin are forbidden for a gentile to do because they are a sign of the covenant between Israel and HaShem.

What are the full list of the forbidden mitzvot ?

Comment: How do you know a gentile may not put on Tefillin?

Comment: @mil the Raadbaz was chochech and decided to be stringent in regards to tefillin, mezuzot, and scrolls(Raadbaz on Hilchot Melachim 10:10). This is in regards to bnei Noach and not goyim(Hilchot Melachim 10:10). Goyim should not be doing anything but studying the seven laws of the children of Noah(Hilchot Melachim 10:9).

Comment: @DoubleAA I did read it in several Jewish websites.

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw an answer to a similar question and it goes like that:

Radbaz says

"In any case, when it comes to mitzvot that require sanctity and purity, such as [wearing] tefillin or [writing] a sefer Torah or a mezuzah, I deliberated and am stringent¹: we should not allow them [non-Jews] to do so."

Comment: "Gentile" needs to be properly defined. There is not such thing as a "gentile" in halacha. "Gentile" is too broad of a term. There are many types of non-Jews in halacha.

Comment: It should be noted that the Rambam in Hilchos Mezuzah 5:11 and Hilchos Tzizts 3:9 holds one should not leave a mezuzah for a non jew and one ahould not sell a garmant with tzizts on it beacsue the non jew may wear it and mingle with a Jew and kill them,one can maybeblearn from this that these 2 mitzvis are prohibited for a non jew,or one can say that a Jew cannot activly leave these 2 mitzvos to a non jew but for a rightous non jew to do it themselevs is permmisble like it says on Hilchos Melachaim,tazurich iyun

Comment: I was under the impression that non-Jews could wear tefillin if they wanted. Where did you read specifically where it says they cannot? Plus, "gentile" is a big word to throw around. Within Judaism, there are different "types" of non-Jews. (Bnei Noach are a good example of non-Jews in a good light.)

Comment: I suppose an Amalekite is forbidden from killing himself.

Comment: I'm not sure that's so simple, Clint Eastwood. Anyway, here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17789/can-a-non-jew-don-tefillin is related. Also, I think it would be important to discern between "dina d'Gemorra" and a horaah which is not m'ikkar hadin. Without having seen the Radbaz, I would assume from the lashon quoted here that it is not m'ikkar hadin.

Answer (score 1):

The Raadbaz was choichech and decided to be stringent in regards to tefillin, mezuzot, and scrolls(Raadbaz on Hilchot Melachim 10:10). This is in regards to *bnei Noach* and not *goyim*(Hilchot Melachim 10:10). Rambam states that *bnei Noach* can do any of the mitzvot as long as they do it properly(Hilchot Melachim 10:10). *Goyim*, which are idol-worshipping non-Jews(Hilchot Machalot Assurot 11:8), should not be doing anything but being involved in the seven laws of the children of Noah(Hilchot Melachim 10:9). A person should be pure before engaging in holiness.

It's my personal opinion that the Raadbaz was choichech(he deliberated) on the matter because there are two main types of *bnei Noach*. *Bnei Noach* that do things for their own sake and *bnei Noach* that do things for the sake of Torah(Hilchot Melachim 8:10-12). These days, because the Yovel year is not practiced a Jewish beit din cannot bring the fear to the *ben Noach* to properly determine his kavanah(intention). Such a *ben Noach* accepted would be a ger toshav and then part of klal Yisrael. The other type of *ben Noach* would most likely not come before the beit din. This is why I think the Raadbaz was being stringent.

All *goyim* by default, are idol-worshippers until said otherwise(Gittin 45b, Hullin 13a, Hilchot Maachalot Assurot 11:8, R"ITVA on Makos 9a, Chasam Sofer on Sanhedrin). However, that does not mean they're always idol-worshippers. They could explicitly state themselves as not idol-worshippers. Once they do that, they come out of the geder/category of *goy* and into *ben Noach*.

Answer (score 0):

The list is:

1. Keeping Shabbes like we do
2. Keeping Yamim Tovim like we do
3. Torahstudy what does not concern the Sheva Mitzvot
4. Receiving aliyah/laynen Torah in shul
5. putting, writing and wearing tefillin
6. write a Sefer Torah

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Very few people reading this page will know you personally, so most people will have no reason to believe you. Can you [edit] in some source for your claim?

Comment: Rambam's Mishneh Torah, in the section on Laws of Kings.

Comment: @Devoirele I don't see the word tefillin in that entire work. Clearly it is not the source of all your claims.

Comment: Welcome! Consider taking the following two-minute [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site.

Comment: I also heard that a gentile should not recite shmone esrei

Comment: @DoubleAA, you are right. Slicha. Source is the Path of the Rightious Gentle of the RaMBaM.

Comment: @Devoirele what about wearing kippa ?

Comment: @ mil, it is allowed for a non-Jew to wear a Kippa. In some occasions non-jews are obligated to wear a kippa. When they go to synagoge or visit a suka.  Sometimes rabbi's ask non-jews to wear jewish symbols to show solidarity. http://www.dailystormer.com/chief-rabbi-of-holland-its-normal-to-be-called-a-dirty-jew-nowadays/

Comment: Also anything which requires kavana in creating to be used for a mitzvah such as making wool or leather for tzitzis or tefilin. As far as learning goes I'm pretty sure they can also learn about prayer, charity, honoring one's parents, marriage, and developing good character traits even though not directly related to the 7 mitzvas as these subjects can help them be better people

Comment: Is a gentile allowed to kill an Amaleki?

Comment: @NBZ, we don't know who is Amaleki anymore, and I'm pretty sure that dina d'malchusa would qualify that as murder b'yameinu.

Comment: 7. Eating Korban Pesach

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Irrelevant, no? The OP didn't ask what is applicable today, only for a *full* list...

Comment: @NBZ, relavent, yes, but perhaps lifnei iver in case someone tries to kill someone whom he suspects to be an Amaleki now.