# Can a non jew obey some of the 613 commandments?

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah

The Noahide covenant was for the whole mankind
and even a non-Jew can enter heaven by following them.

However, can a non-Jew obey some of the mitzvot commandments that he wishes to obey (moral values, etc) like not taking revenge, honoring the old people etc.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62441/170

Comment: @msh210 If it is considered a dupe, what's the best way to handle it? The 2 answers there were voted minus 1 each by the community so the value of the dupe answers are not very good? Should it be duped and people required to post better answers over there, or should it stand here?

Comment: Note that many of the mitzvos are already included in the seven categories (I think over 280). Most if not all of the others are ritual mitzvos that do not apply to Bnai Noach (like shabbos or tum'a). One would first have to determine which mitzvos are in the appropriate category before giving a complete answer.

Comment: @DavidKenner Only a moderator can make something a duplicate of a question that doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: And is it a coincidence that the other question was just bumped by Community?

Comment: obviously a gentile would never get circumcised neither will he keep shabbats etc. I was talking about the commandments which are for the sake of morality like to give charity , to help your neighbor. i see no reason why a non jew can't obey these commandments?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The other question is asking what mitzvos a non Jew may not do and this is asking what mitzvos a non Jew may do. While these questions are very similar they are not the same as each other